# Please could someone decode this Albanian phonetics rule for me?

Tags: phonetics, albanian

I was reading through a paper on Albanian stress as I am learning Albanian. The general rule, which the paper [available here: [https://home.uni-leipzig.de/jtrommer/papers/alb.pdf]](https://home.uni-leipzig.de/jtrommer/papers/alb.pdf) claimed functioned for 97% of Albanian words, was as follows:

[image]

Rule 3 confused me a lot, especially 3.a. Could someone possibly explain what is meant by 3a as I don't know what a 'full vowel' [and couldn't find out by searching, either] - Thanks a lot if you do.

Comment: FYI this is part of phonology, not a phonetics rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page entitled ‘Sensitivity to Syllable Weight’ which is page 8 of the paper and directly precedes the page with the rule cited in the question has a chart which clearly explains the rule and unambiguously shows that by “full vowel” all the vowels except *ë* (schwa [ə]) are meant. Also, page 10 has 3 examples of applying the rule that verify that all.

In the algorithm, “Full_Vowel” is *false* if the vowel is **ë**, otherwise it is *true*. So, you stress the **final** syllable of the base form (B) in two cases:

1. if this final syllable has no **ë** and it is closed;
2. if the nucleus of the final syllable is **i**, **a**, **u**, in this case it doesn't matter if it is closed or open.

And do not forget it is all about the final syllable of the word **base**, and not of an inflected word form.